Connecting to Elasticache Redis Nodes locally using SSH Tunneling through Jump host
Currently we have a setup where we setup an EC2 jump host to setup SSH tunneling to our RDS instances using a docker container. I needed to use the same setup to setup SSH tunnel to our Elasticache Redis nodes. So I created a separate folder for redis, modified the script so that it discovers the redis nodes instead of rds instances and sets up the tunnel using the appropriate port 6379. The tunnel seems to be connected successfully but I cannot run redis-cli commands from my local cli as the curser just hangs.
Anyone here set something like this up?
So my setup is as follows:

Run command "docker build --no-cache=true --tag  -f ./redis-connect/ssm-connect/Dockerfile ."
Run command "docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws -e AWS_PROFILE -p 6379:6379  ci"
a. The aws_profile I connect to is a dev env and the code in my script pulls all ci resources, hence ci at the end of the command.
3.An interactive terminal appears with the id of the ec2 instances used as a jumphost, port number and a lists of hosts to choose from.
I press 1 to connect to the first host in the list and then the tunnel is opened on that node.
From there I use my local terminal to run commands but when I run "redis-cli -p 6379, the curser just blinks.

Any help would be great. If I need to supply the code in my docker files I can.
